# Criar paginação no CRUD com Jquery e Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tenho esse código em HTML/JavaScript/Jquery e preciso criar uma paginação com os elementos do servidor. A página exibi os elementos de 5 em 5, eu queria saber como faço para avançar para as próximas páginas e voltar para anteriores.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Clientes

```
Nome Cliente: <input type="text" id="id1">
<br><br>
Uf: <input type="text" id="id2">
<br><br>
Renda Mensal: <input type="text" id="id3">

<br><br>

<button type="button" id="id4">Novo/Alterar</button>

<br><br>

<table id="demo"></table>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#id4').click(function()
            {
                $.ajax
                ({
                      type: 'get',
                      datatype: 'json',
                      data:'num_rec_per_page=5',
                      url:'https://clienteweb2017.000webhostapp.com/crud_ajax_json/getDadosClientes.php',
                      success: function(retorno)
                      {

                          var dados = JSON.parse(retorno);
                          var linhas = "";

                          $.each(dados.data,function(key,value)
                          {

                              linhas += "<tr><td>"+ value.id +"</td> <td>"+ value.nome + "</td> <td>"+ value.uf +"</td> <td>"+value.rendamensal +"</td>"+"<td> <button id='editar'>Editar</button> </td> "+" <td> <button id='apagar'>Apagar</button> </td> </tr>";
                          });

                          $("#demo").html(linhas);  
                      }
                   })
            })

            $('#id4').click(function()
            {

                var nome = $('#id1').val();
                var uf = $('#id2').val();
                var rm = $('#id3').val();

                $.ajax
                ({
                      type: 'get',
                      datatype: 'json',
                      data: 'nome='+nome+'&uf='+uf+'&rendamensal='+rm,
                      url:'https://clienteweb2017.000webhostapp.com/crud_ajax_json/createCliente.php',
                      success: function(data)
                      {
                          console.log(data);
                      }
                })

            });

            $("body").on("click","#editar",function()
            {
                var nome = $('#id1').val();
                var uf = $('#id2').val();
                var rm = $('#id3').val();
                var id= $(this).parent().siblings().eq(0).text();

                $.ajax
                ({
                      type: 'get',
                      datatype: 'json',
                      data: 'id='+ id +'&nome='+nome+'&uf='+uf+'&rendamensal='+ rm,
                      url:'https://clienteweb2017.000webhostapp.com/crud_ajax_json/updateCliente.php',
                      success: function(data1)
                      {
                          console.log(data1);
                      }
                })

            });

            $("body").on("click","#apagar",function()
            {
                var id= $(this).parent().siblings().eq(0).text();
                $.ajax
                ({
                      type: 'get',
                      datatype: 'json',
                      data: 'id='+id,
                      url:'https://clienteweb2017.000webhostapp.com/crud_ajax_json/deleteCliente.php',
                      success: function(data2)
                      {
                          console.log(data2);
                      }
                })
            });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá!

Desculpe se estou enganado, mas você parece ser um novato no assunto. Dê uma olhada na opção que o **bootstrap** oferece para uma paginação super eficiente:
https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/components/pagination/

É bastante simples de entender e implementar. Vale lembrar que utilizar classes prontas e frameworks frontend são, muitas vezes, ótimas saídas, mas nada te impede de criar seus próprios scripts e estilos para criar os efeitos visuais que você deseja.